# Cordova build Android return error Execution failed for task ':transformDexArchiveWithExternalLibsDexMergerForArmv7Debug'

Tags: android, cordova, build

This the the error my facing when run cordova build android. Try cordova clean it does not help. Try remove platform and add platform also does not help.

```
Error: /Users/xeersoft/icsv1/icsv1/cordova/platforms/android/gradlew: Command failed with exit code 1 Error output:
    Note: Some input files use or override a deprecated API.
    Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
    Note: Some input files use or override a deprecated API.
    Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
    Note: Some input files use unchecked or unsafe operations.
    Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
    Dex: Error converting bytecode to dex:
    Cause: com.android.dex.DexException: Multiple dex files define Lcom/google/zxing/common/detector/MonochromeRectangleDetector;
        UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL EXCEPTION:
        com.android.dex.DexException: Multiple dex files define Lcom/google/zxing/common/detector/MonochromeRectangleDetector;

    com.android.dex.DexException: Multiple dex files define Lcom/google/zxing/common/detector/MonochromeRectangleDetector;
            at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.readSortableTypes(DexMerger.java:661)
            at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.getSortedTypes(DexMerger.java:616)
            at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.mergeClassDefs(DexMerger.java:598)
            at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.mergeDexes(DexMerger.java:171)
            at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.merge(DexMerger.java:198)
            at com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveMergerCallable.call(DexArchiveMergerCallable.java:61)
            at com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveMergerCallable.call(DexArchiveMergerCallable.java:36)
            at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask$AdaptedCallable.exec(ForkJoinTask.java:1424)
            at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:289)
            at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.runTask(ForkJoinPool.java:1056)
            at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1692)
            at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:157)

    FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

    * What went wrong:
    Execution failed for task ':transformDexArchiveWithDexMergerForArmv7Debug'.
    > com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: com.android.dex.DexException: Multiple dex files define Lcom/google/zxing/common/detector/MonochromeRectangleDetector;

    * Try:
    Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

    * Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

    BUILD FAILED in 24s
```

Comment: in build gradle, i set mutiDexEnable true

defaultConfig {
        multiDexEnabled true
        versionCode cdvVersionCode ?: new BigInteger("" + privateHelpers.extractIntFromManifest("versionCode"))
        applicationId privateHelpers.extractStringFromManifest("package")

        if (cdvMinSdkVersion != null) {
            minSdkVersion cdvMinSdkVersion
        }
    }

Comment: Please do not use comments for adding additional information. Use [edit] instead